# How to control the navigation drawer items through a checkbox on android

Tags: android, navigation, drawer

If I had many item in navigation drawer
I want a way for a user to have the ability to show or hide any item through a checkbox ...
If it is correct, the item is displayed.
If it is correct is removed, the item disappears.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1UEk.png

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the navigation menu like this :

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
Menu navMenu = navigationView.getMenu(nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.menunav_tohide);
navMenu.setVisible(false);
```